# Retrieve the names of employees who is making least in their departments

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

```
EMPLOYEE (Fname, Lname, Ssn, Salary, Dno)

DEPARTMENT (Dname, Dno, Location)
```

I want to list the names of all employees making the least in their department

I have come up with this

```
select min(E.Salary) from EMPLOYEE E group by E.Dno;
```

but how do I join the EMPLOYEE table with it and display the 'Fname' and 'Lname';

Comment: Do you need a query that works unchanged for both SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL server ? What is the expected result if two employees have the min salary in their departement ?

Comment: I want a query that will work with Oracle. If two employees have minimum salary, then I want the name of both employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic functions would be best but this would also work:

```
select *
  from employee e
 where salary = (select min(x.salary) from employee x where x.dno = e.dno)
```

Comment: I want it for each department

Comment: @AmeyKellkar that will show exactly what you want; the employees making the lowest amount at each department.

Comment: I tried it on my Oracle, and yes it is giving me the exact output as I needed. But can you elaborate on how this works? Thank you!

Comment: @AmeyKelkar it is a correlated subquery, on each row of the employee table the subquery will find the lowest salary amount from the table for the department on that particular row (the subquery selects a new amount each time), if the salary on the current row matches the lowest salary on that table for the same department, the row comes back, otherwise it doesn't

Comment: From `performance` point of view, `analytic function` is better than subquery approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Analytic` function, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY DNO ORDER BY SALARY) as RN`. So, `WHERE RN = 1` will give you the employee with least salary in each department.

Remember, if there are two employees with same salary, then you need to use `DENSE_RANK` to avoid similar rank.

Note : This answer is for Oracle.

Comment: Should work well for SQL Server - at least 2012 and later - too.

Comment: Isn't there a way without using Analytic functions?

Comment: @Amey kelkar, There are many approaches, but, from `performance` point of view, `analytic function` is better. Since you `scan` the table only once. Rest other approaches as shown are not efficient.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, thanks for letting me know. I haven't worked on Sql Server, so I have put up a disclaimer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it is to check that no one with a lower salary exists in the same department;

```
SELECT e1.* 
FROM employee e1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM employee e2 WHERE e1.dno = e2.dno AND e1.salary > e2.salary
);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d456d/1).